# Ubuntu won't login after disk migration

Tags: ubuntu, partition, login

I have a weird problem here. I migrated my GF's drive from HDD to SSD. I had to shrink Windows partition and move partitions around to fit 750GB HDD to 512GB SSD. I think I did everything fine. Windows and Ubuntu **both boot** to the login screens. Only Ubuntu doesn't let her log in (both with screen keyboard and normal keyboard). Obviously, I though this is `lightdm` issue. I tried to login via shell <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. That doesn't work either. I have live USB, which I can boot from to mount linux partition. I didn't see anything unusual in the kern.log or syslog.

So then I tried to start recovery mode but that ends up showing usual login screen instead of the recovery menu. I am really puzzled here. If it would be a partition issue, it wouldn't have booted at all. Her home directory is in the same partition as the system. Whole Linux system is in same partition + there is swap partition.

I don't know how to proceed from here but reinstalling Ubuntu. What else can there be? Or how can I find the cause of the issue?

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, I didn't explain the keyboard part nicely. Keyboard works all the time. The reason for me to try to log in with on screen keyboard was to eliminate any localization issues. The keyboard is german and if Ubuntu identifies it as US for some reason, special characters and y/z would be misplaced without the user noticing it.

Edit - How did I migrate the drive:
I have reduced the windows partition and moved partitions (inluding Ubuntu) after the windows partition after the reduced Windows partition in Gparted. This was done to move every partition before the end of the target drive. I cloned the source to target with `dd`. At some point as expected `dd` stopped with the "no space left on the device" error. Gparted didn't show the partition table of the new drive at this point, because the partition table had a wrong device size defined (remnant from the previous device). As suggested on the internet, `fdisk` corrected that part. After this, I replaced the drives on the machine and I was simply able to boot both with Ubuntu and Windows. Windows has been working fine so far. Only in Ubuntu login doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by:
"Only Ubuntu doesn't let her log in (both with screen keyboard and normal keyboard)"
Keyboard doesn't work on the login screen?

Comment: I mean that in Windows she can log in and it is not a keyboard issue. Sometimes with certain languages, if keyboard is not recognized correctly, people type wrong password without realizing. I wanted to exclude that by using on screen keyboard. But keyboard works.

Comment: So in ubuntu the keyboard stops working at the login screen?
Is it a similar issue with the mouse?

Comment: No keyboard always works, but since you don't see the password you are typing, you might type the wrong password without knowing. That happens for instance with keyboards of other languages. Ubuntu sometimes doesn't recognize the language of the keyboard and thinks it is US. Then all the special characters, some letters rearrange. If you have a german keyboard, typing "y" would result in "z". Often people don't recognize that. On screen keyboard is a safer way to eliminate that confusion. But keyboard works all the time. It is not a keyboard issue. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier.

Comment: How did you perform the migration?

Comment: system can boot and run fine but users can't login if permissions on their home directory is bad.  If you are hitting `ctrl+alt+F1` and logging in on a VT then that removes lightdm, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan On VT, I can't login either. That was the solution I have found too.

Comment: @Kusalananda I explained it now at the end of my question.

Comment: have you updated the uuids in fstab after the migration?

Comment: @vfbsilva I didn't do that, I will give it a try. Any idea, how that can affect login?

Comment: I wild guess, you moved the partitions, somehow UEFI knows where your system is and is able to get you to the login screen. But the system hangs as the partitions are messed

Comment: You can try resetting the password. Boot from the Live USB, mount the root partition to say... `/mnt` and then run: `passwd -R /mnt [USERNAME]`

Comment: @vfbsilva uuids for the linux partition, swap and /boot/efi are the same in /etc/fstab of Ubuntu partition and /dev/disk/by-uuid in gparted live USB.

Comment: @genon this excludes my supposition. Have you tried to chroot in the machine to check for relevant logs?

Comment: @vfbsilva I could not chroot "/bin/bash not found" due to different architechtire (gparted=32bit ubuntu=64bit). I have now Ubuntu Live USB to do that. However, I checked /var/log/kern.log and syslog, I couldn't see anything relevant there.

Comment: what about boot and last.log?

Comment: @vfbsilva Nothing really. Only lastlog (there wasn't any last.log) I have found a lot of weird characters repeating (^@).

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I have salvaged the data and reinstalled Ubuntu (this time 18.04). Newly installed Ubuntu booted and allowed login on the freshly created user. This is not a real answer, therefore I won't accept it.